# Jill's flight security woes

Tags: story, situation

Jill is on a flight when she spots her friend a few seats behind her.

She tries to get his attention, and is immediately tackled by security.

What did Jill do to warrant such a response?

Answer (score 10):

This is an old joke... Jill has...

> made the mistake of shouting **"Hi Jack!"** (think '[Jack and Jill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_Jill_(nursery_rhyme))' of nursery rhyme fame...) on an aeroplane. Of course, the security officer hears this as '[hijack](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hijack)' and immediately moves to stop the vessel being taken over, tackling her to the floor.

In fact, there is a video on YouTube which suggests that this exact joke:

> was even used in a [deleted scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kf3bw8KEZ44) in the 1980 movie *[Airplane!](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080339/)*

Comment: I genuinely had no idea this was an old joke :)

Comment: @rybo111 In fact, I've managed to find what purports to be a deleted scene from *Airplane!* which uses this exact setup! (See the link in my answer...)

Comment: It turns out that rot13 (obz be onz) is also a name of African or Korean origin. Try shouting that in the plane :)

Comment: I should also note rot13 (Gur anzr "Wvyy" vf n fvtavsvpnag pyhr)

Comment: @rybo111 Indeed - I made an instant connection with that one. I'll edit to mention it explicitly...

Comment: @Stiv You're not only a experienced puzzler, but also a Joker ;-)